# Swift - background image does not fit (showing small part of the all image)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, background-image

I am trying to set up my background photo to the view,
the `img` dimention is `1900x1000`. It's showing only small part of the image and does not fit it in.
This is what I have tried :

```
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
    let imageview = UIImageView(image: image1)
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.view.addSubview(imageview)
```

2) for some reason after I set the background image the label that was in the view "disappear", my guess it that its behind the background image, how can I set it to be at the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScaleAspectFill` will fill `imageview`'s `frame` while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image. So if the image is the wrong size, you need to change `imageview`'s `frame` or autolayout constraints.

Regarding question #2, `addSubview(_:)` adds the subview to the front.

You could instead use `insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)` to place `imageview`  below your label. Alternatively, you could pass your label into `bringSubviewToFront(_:)`.

Comment: solved for second problem ! thank you , didnt understand what to do with the first one, can you exaplain more?

Comment: `imageview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)`, for example.